# CLang LLVM writing DAG DOT files to current directory

Tags: unix, clang, llvm, dot, directed-acyclic-graphs

I've successfully generate DAG DOT files output from LLVM LLC tool by running `llc -view-dag-combine1-dags src.ll` targeting my IR generated code from `clang -S -emit-llvm src.c`
However it default writes output DOT files to temp directory:

> Writing
>   '/var/folders/yr/bkw72rn11p7454jkmnnn7p780000gn/T/sunit-dag.foo:entry-b6411e.dot'...
>   done.  Trying 'open' program... Remember to erase graph file:
>   /var/folders/yr/bkw72rn11p7454jkmnnn7p780000gn/T/sunit-dag.foo:entry-b6411e.dot

I've tried too many workarounds to get files to my current directory even by trying to list, sort and copy latest modified file in this temp directory however many files may be generated by running one generating command (***unknown number of files***) so my temp solution failed!

**Question**:
How to redirect those files to my current directory?
I'll welcome any answers even workarounds ones.

Note:
Clang, LLVM, LLC versions: 3.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot.

Long answer: there is llvm::createGraphFilename() routine inside lib/Support/GraphWriter.cpp which is responsible for graph file names and which unconditionally creates temporary files. Therefore you'd need to change this function and recompile LLVM in order to obtain the desired functionality.